# Will C# be available on other platforms soon?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

Microsoft announced a open-source cross-platform .NET 5. I know that there are librarys like mono that act as a framework for cross-platforming with C# - but does the release of .NET 5 mean that it will be easier to work with C# on other platforms without MONO, Xamarin etc?

Comment: C# is *already* available on pretty much every platform you can name...

Comment: @MarcGravell doesn't it require libraries as mono to run on other plateform than Windows?

Comment: Well, if it doesn´t need mono, why does mono exist then? And i love downvotes without comments. Soo nice. Next time i will know how to ask my questions.

Comment: @MathiasS. i think the OP is asking if there is a way to run C# on another platform without the use of librairie like mono. I though .NET 5 will compile in native code.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes the C# ports are available, but the question remains are they the serious option for the professional developers? In fact are they serious contenders, why would I choose Mono over other well defined options on Linux.

Cross platform support and Microsoft's official support were  the big missing links. 
Current availability of Mono, Xamarin is due to C# being an ECMA standard, which is not a reassurance for serious development

Comment: Microsoft isn't going to be implementing .Net for platforms other than Windows, Mac and Linux, but they ARE making the source code more open source, which will allow third parties to do so more easily. You'd still need something like Mono on those other platforms, of course.

Comment: We should not down vote based on whims and fancies, its an innocuous question, which is well within its right to be asked on the current portal, tag. User is just asking for more details and clarity.I have upvoted to counter at least one down vote

Comment: At the very least, don't downvote without commenting why!

Comment: @MrinalKamboj agreed with you

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's the same system as Java and their JVM. They don't develop one for each platform but just give specifications developers have to follow to develop a JVM for their OS

Comment: @Ludovic You sure about that? From the link that you gave: *"We are building a .NET Core CLR for Windows, Mac and Linux and it will be both open source and it will be supported by Microsoft. It'll all happen at https://github.com/dotnet."*

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think they will give a first implementation of their core and every developer can fork it and improve it for each system. But i'm not sure, if you have more information about what they will really do

Comment: @Ludovic From [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-open-source-of-net-core-framework-net-core-distribution-for-linux-osx-and-free-visual-studio-community-edition): *"we are also going to release an official distribution of the .NET Core for Linux, as well as an official distribution of .NET Core for the Mac operation system as well"* - sounds like a proper distro to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 5 will allow cross development, have a look at this blog posts:

[Microsoft takes .NET open source and cross-platform, adds new development capabilities with Visual Studio 2015, .NET 2015 and Visual Studio Online](http://news.microsoft.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform-adds-new-development-capabilities-with-visual-studio-2015-net-2015-and-visual-studio-online/)

And:

[Announcing .NET 2015 - .NET as Open Source, .NET on Mac and Linux, and Visual Studio Community](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETasOpenSourceNETonMacandLinuxandVisualStudioCommunity.aspx)

> Delivering on its promise to support cross-platform development, Microsoft is providing the full .NET server stack in open source, including ASP.NET, the .NET compiler, the .NET Core Runtime, Framework and Libraries, enabling developers to build with .NET across Windows, Mac or Linux. Through this implementation, Microsoft will work closely with the open source community, taking contributions for future improvements to .NET and will work through the .NET Foundation.

[source](http://news.microsoft.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform-adds-new-development-capabilities-with-visual-studio-2015-net-2015-and-visual-studio-online/)